# where to find the address of the NFT contract I created on opensea

Tags: metamask, nft, opensea

I want to see my NFTs in metamask, where can I get the contract address to add to metamask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to use the browser extension of Metamask you wont be able to visualise your NFTs according to a [Metamask article](https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360058238591-NFT-tokens-in-your-MetaMask-wallet) released 7 days ago.

You can however view them if you have the Metamask mobile app. If your NFTs are on Ethereum they should populate automatically. If they dont populate automatically you can try the steps that are outlined in that article:

1. Find the NFT's address. On OpenSea, for example, on the NFT's page under Details, there is a blue hyperlinked value labelled "Contract Address". If you click on this, it will take you to the contract's address on Etherscan; at the top-left of that page, there should be an icon labelled "Contract", and to the right, a long string of letters and numbers. This is the address of the contract that created your NFT. Click on the "copy" icon to the right of the address, and you'll have it on your clipboard.
2. In MetaMask Mobile, tap on the 'NFTs' tab, scroll down and tap on the "+ ADD NFTs" link. Paste the NFT's address from your clipboard into the "Address" box.
3. Find the NFT's ID. A collectible's ID is a unique identifier since no two NFTs are alike. Again, on OpenSea this number is under "Details". Make a note of it, or copy it onto your clipboard.
4. Paste the ID into the box marked "ID" in MetaMask Mobile, tap on the "ADD" button, and your NFTs should appear under the NFTs tab.

Comment: I did everything as you said and everything worked out, but I released 210,000,000,000 copies, but in the metamask I just see the OpenSea Colections #id inscription that I indicated. this is not what i wanted

Comment: When you say 210,000,000,000 copies? Do you mean unique NFTs? Or do you actually mean copies? If you actually mean copies that means you are probably using a ERC1155 and metamask doesnt support this yet

Comment: I followed your instructions, but it says "Personal address detected. Input the collectible contract address." What is that?

Comment: @NoahDemauro it appears you are trying to add a NFT using a regular users address. You need to get the address of the collection that your smart contract is from. Or more simply you just need to input the address of your nft